# Unable to start the react app template in visual studio

Tags: create-react-app, visual-studio-2022

This is another reason why I hate npm so much. It has a lot of dependencies and it's really hard to figure out what goes wrong. It was working one day, and then it stopped with not apparent issue.

I created a react template project with my visual studio community 2022. Right off the batch, without modifying anything, I ran `npm i` and started the project and this is the error that I get:

`ERROR in Failed to load parser 'babel-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app`

Things I have tried:

- Delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` again
- Run `npm install eslint --save-dev`

Can someone tell me what in the world that I need to do to fix this error ? I can't get my head around of me that something just out of the box is not working at all. So frustrating....

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed after I updated `nodejs`, uninstall and reinstall the latest `npm` version. Hope it helps someone.